How can I change fields in a dataframe based on the most common valid value?
I have a data set of resident demographics. I need to clean the data up. People put things in the system wrong.
On the first interaction someone might not know the race or ethnicity of the person but on the second or third interaction with the same person they might get the information.
So, I am hoping to copy the new information to the previous lines.  Each interaction will have an incident number but if they interacted with the same person it will have a resident.ID attached. As you'll notice the responses are all over the place.
Here's the example dataset:
df <- structure(list(Incident.Number = c("2024-00087969", "2024-00086500", 
"2024-00084279", "2024-00083770", "2024-00082302", "2023-00436775", 
"2023-00336547", "2023-00163396", "2023-00072504", "2023-00072378", 
"2023-00071167", "2023-00097209", "2023-00079243", "2023-00077822", 
"2024-00036963", "2023-00204364", "2023-00183672", "2023-00023113", 
"2023-00266448", "2023-00258926", "2023-00257665", "2023-00269442", 
"2023-00266719", "2023-00146792", "2023-00210787", "2024-00067990", 
"2024-00103119", "2023-00446192", "2023-00403647", "2023-00158407", 
"2023-00080653"), Resident.ID = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "653367039", 
"653367039", "653367039", "653367039", "653367039", "653367039", 
"393246263", "393246263", "393246263", "393246263", "223171241", 
"223171241", "223171241", "404653450", "404653450", "404653450", 
"488298040", "488298040", "488298040", "573993743", "573993743", 
"573993743", "621872041", "621872041", "621872041", "747325855"
), Sex = c("Unknown", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Unknown", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Other", "Other", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female"), Ethnicity = c("Non-Hispanic", 
"Non-Hispanic", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Hispanic", 
"Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Non-Hispanic", 
"Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Unknown", "Non-Hispanic", "Non-Hispanic", 
"Non-Hispanic", "Unknown", "Non-Hispanic", "Non-Hispanic", "Non-Hispanic", 
"Unknown", "Unknown", "Non-Hispanic", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Non-Hispanic", 
"Preferred not to Answer", "Unknown", "Preferred not to Answer"
), Race = c("Black or African American", "Black or African American", 
"Black or African American", "White", "White", "Preferred not to Answer", 
"White", "White", "White", "Preferred not to Answer", "White", 
"White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", 
"White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "Black or African American", 
"Black or African American", "Black or African American", "Black or African American", 
"Black or African American", "Black or African American", "White"
)), row.names = 553:583, class = "data.frame")

For ID 653367039 I want all the rows to say Sex: Female, Race: White, Ethnicity: Non-Hispanic
For ID 393246263 some of the demographics conflict so it should go to the value that appears the most. Returning Sex: Female / Ethnicity: Hispanic / Race: White
If the resident ID is NA nothing should change in the demographic columns.
I tried the following code:
This started replacing actual demographic data with unknown or preferred not to answer when I wanted the opposite.
# Function to replace "Unknown" or "Preferred not to Answer" with the most common non-"Unknown"/"Preferred not to Answer" value
replace_unknown <- function(x) {
  if (length(unique(x)) > 2) {
    # If there are more than two unique values (excluding NA, Unknown, and Preferred not to Answer),
    # replace "Unknown" or "Preferred not to Answer" with the most common non-"Unknown"/"Preferred not to Answer" value
    table_x <- table(x)
    max_val <- names(sort(table_x[table_x != max(table_x)], decreasing = TRUE))[1]
    x <- ifelse(x %in% c("Unknown", "Preferred not to Answer"), max_val, x)
  } else {
    # If there are only "Unknown" and "Preferred not to Answer" values, default to "Unknown" or "Preferred not to Answer"
    x <- ifelse(x == "Unknown", "Unknown", "Preferred not to Answer")
  }
  return(x)
}

# Apply the logic to the dataframe
df_cleaned <- df %>%
  group_by(Resident.ID) %>%
  mutate(
    Race = ifelse(is.na(Resident.ID), Race, {
      # Replace "Unknown" or "Preferred not to Answer" with the most common non-"Unknown"/"Preferred not to Answer" value
      race_table <- table(Race)
      max_race <- names(sort(race_table[race_table != max(race_table)], decreasing = TRUE))[1]
      max_race <- ifelse(length(max_race) == 0, "Unknown", max_race)
      replace_unknown(Race)
    }),
    Ethnicity = ifelse(is.na(Resident.ID), Ethnicity, {
      # Replace "Unknown" or "Preferred not to Answer" with the most common non-"Unknown"/"Preferred not to Answer" value
      ethnicity_table <- table(Ethnicity)
      max_ethnicity <- names(sort(ethnicity_table[ethnicity_table != max(ethnicity_table)], decreasing = TRUE))[1]
      max_ethnicity <- ifelse(length(max_ethnicity) == 0, "Unknown", max_ethnicity)
      replace_unknown(Ethnicity)
    }),
    Sex = ifelse(is.na(Resident.ID), Sex, {
      # Replace "Unknown" or "Preferred not to Answer" with the most common non-"Unknown"/"Preferred not to Answer" value
      sex_table <- table(Sex)
      max_sex <- names(sort(sex_table[sex_table != max(sex_table)], decreasing = TRUE))[1]
      max_sex <- ifelse(length(max_sex) == 0, "Unknown", max_sex)
      replace_unknown(Sex)
    })
  )

I've been trying different versions of this and its just not working. I look forward to some help. TT.TT

Replacing with the most prevalent valid value per Resident.ID:
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    across(Sex:Race, \(x) {
      x_valid <- x[!(x %in% c("Unknown", "Preferred not to Answer"))]
      if (length(x_valid) == 0 || all(is.na(Resident.ID))) x
  else names(which.max(table(x_valid)))
    }),
    .by = Resident.ID
  )

Result:
    Incident.Number Resident.ID     Sex               Ethnicity                      Race
553   2024-00087969        <NA> Unknown            Non-Hispanic Black or African American
554   2024-00086500        <NA>  Female            Non-Hispanic Black or African American
555   2024-00084279        <NA>  Female                 Unknown Black or African American
556   2024-00083770        <NA>  Female                 Unknown                     White
557   2024-00082302        <NA>  Female                 Unknown                     White
558   2023-00436775   653367039  Female                Hispanic                     White
559   2023-00336547   653367039  Female                Hispanic                     White
560   2023-00163396   653367039  Female                Hispanic                     White
561   2023-00072504   653367039  Female                Hispanic                     White
562   2023-00072378   653367039  Female                Hispanic                     White
563   2023-00071167   653367039  Female                Hispanic                     White
564   2023-00097209   393246263  Female                Hispanic                     White
565   2023-00079243   393246263  Female                Hispanic                     White
566   2023-00077822   393246263  Female                Hispanic                     White
567   2024-00036963   393246263  Female                Hispanic                     White
568   2023-00204364   223171241  Female            Non-Hispanic                     White
569   2023-00183672   223171241  Female            Non-Hispanic                     White
570   2023-00023113   223171241  Female            Non-Hispanic                     White
571   2023-00266448   404653450   Other            Non-Hispanic                     White
572   2023-00258926   404653450   Other            Non-Hispanic                     White
573   2023-00257665   404653450   Other            Non-Hispanic                     White
574   2023-00269442   488298040  Female            Non-Hispanic                     White
575   2023-00266719   488298040  Female            Non-Hispanic                     White
576   2023-00146792   488298040  Female            Non-Hispanic                     White
577   2023-00210787   573993743    Male            Non-Hispanic Black or African American
578   2024-00067990   573993743    Male            Non-Hispanic Black or African American
579   2024-00103119   573993743    Male            Non-Hispanic Black or African American
580   2023-00446192   621872041    Male            Non-Hispanic Black or African American
581   2023-00403647   621872041    Male            Non-Hispanic Black or African American
582   2023-00158407   621872041    Male            Non-Hispanic Black or African American
583   2023-00080653   747325855  Female Preferred not to Answer                     White

You may want to add explicit handling for the case where there are multiple unique values that occur with equal frequency. This solution will just use whichever is first alphabetically.
